# Javascript focus does not work on dynamically loaded input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a HTML markup in a template which has input element. I load it via Ajax call and put in existing html using jQuery's `$(selector).html(response)`.

Basically it is a pop up box which loads from template. After loading pop up box I want to set focus on input box. I've written this code :

`$("#prescribe-input").focus()` after content is appended in existing HTML but it does not work. I tried doing it in traditional javascript way too `document.getElementById("prescribe-input").focus()`

Both do not work. For testing purpose I tried creating sample input box in Index.html of an app and set focus. it works perfectly. The problem is when I load html from template using `$().html()` it does not work.

Any way to focus it properly?

I know the code is very less here but the question is self explanatory I believe.

Comment: You have to include minimal example which replicates your issue, it's unclear what is your issue, could be many things

Comment: If the element existed and the selector was correct, setting the focus would work just fine on a dynamic element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using  `jquery` then you can use `.on()` on dynamically generated elements

```
$("#prescribe-input").on( "focus", function() {
  //do what ever you want
});
```

Comment: How on earth would a delegated event handler work with ***setting*** the focus to an element ?

Comment: and anyway, you aren't delegating event here

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in the callback function:

```
$(selector).html(response, function(){
   $("#prescribe-input").focus();
})
```

Comment: Why would that matter, `html()` is synchronous ?

Comment: may be OP is putting focus before content is appened.

Comment: The OP probably is, but using a callback for a synchronous method won't really help ?

Comment: i just read it again i think there is id duplicacy. another elem with same `id` most probably available in there.

Comment: There is no other ID as the same element. I made sure that the focusing logic is called only after appending HTML element.